# Quadric fitting

Tags: matrices, optimization, quadrics

Let's have two quadrics (as input): $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. These are symmetric 4x4 matrices of reals.

I want to find a transformation (9 degrees of liberty: 3 for rotation, 3 for scale and 3 for translation) such that:

\begin{equation}
    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{argmin}
    T^* = \argmin_{T \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}} \| T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2 \|_F^2
\end{equation}

That is, applying a rigid transformation to the first quadric to align it with the second. So far, I decomposed this problem like this:

\begin{align}
    E
    &= \| T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2 \|_F^2 \\
    &= \text{tr}((T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2)(T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2)^\top) \\
    &= \text{tr}(T^\top Q_1 T T^\top Q_1 T) - 2\,\text{tr}(T^\top Q_1 T Q_2) + \text{tr}(Q_2^2) \\
\\
    \frac{\partial E}{\partial T}
    &= 4Q_1 T (T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2) \\
\\
    \frac{\partial E}{\partial T} = 0 &\Leftrightarrow Q_1 T (T^\top Q_1 T - Q_2) = 0
\end{align}

That gives me 16 polynomial equations for 9 unknowns, but if I try to write it I get an astronomically long expression (and Maple just hang on it).

How can I solve it ?

Comment: Here is an alternative. First get rid of the translations by bringing the centers to the origin (unless you have paraboloids among the two). Then compute the system of orthogonal eigenvectors associated with $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, and try to match them in this way.

Comment: It is possible that I have paraboloids (in fact I can have *any* quadric), but that is a good idea, I will try it !